# How do I measure and compare disk performance of my Hyper-V Windows VM?

Tags: windows, virtualization, performance, hyper-v, hard-drive

I'm not sure whether this sounds stupid or lazy, but I'm really not sure.

[I have a problem](https://serverfault.com/q/423828/54713) with the performance of a VM setup (2008R2-64bit Hyper-V running a 2003R2-32bit Windows server) and I'd like to see whether the disk is the problem.

[I want to time a C++ build.](https://serverfault.com/q/423828/54713) It will take x minutes on the real hardware and x+y minutes on the *single* VM running on this same hardware. (And, `y` is way too large, hence this question.) I guess I would want to run [perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx) during each build and time some counters and then compare the results.

- Should I run perfmon on the host or on the guest (for the build in the VM)?
- **Which counter(s) should I look at?**
- Should I consider anything besides perfmon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the most relevant counters are:

- Disk Bytes/s
- Current Disk Queue Length
- Avg. Disk Queue Length

Benchmarking the disks (both virtual and physical) with [ATTO](http://www.attotech.com/products/product.php?sku=Disk_Benchmark) may be worth a try as well.

Comment: Acutally no, the only relevant is pretty much "seconds/IO". The moment that goes up, the disc is overloaded - the rest needs a LOT of interpretation, this one tells you when the responsiveness goes down. For example - how big is too big for avg queue length? Depends on discs ;) I know a SAN that had 26x256 for queue size without problems.  But Seconds/IO (which should be 0.00x) tells you in one number when things get bad.